# DS3231 on Beaglebone black

Tags: linux-device-driver

I have a Beagle-bone Black(BBB) and I want to wire up my own devices to it (not capes), you might already have heard about the device tree. In my case I wanted to connect a ds3231 RTC device to the I2C bus on the BBB. I have wrote a ds3231 driver code and I have been successful in communicating with the chip by instantiating the device manually as follows :echo ds3231 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-2/new_device. After the device is instantiated, I can see it using i2cdetect tools and loaded it using insmod but my probe function is not getting called. I have an doubt that whenever I am unplugging my Rtc device and plugging it after sometime I am unable to see accurate time it's showing the time of when first time when rtc module is used(2000.01.01).

Comment: You didn't need to write your own driver. It is supported by the "rtc-ds1307" driver (`CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1307`).

Comment: I am a beginner and trying to work on ds3231 rtc module using beagle-bone black. So I need to write device driver code for ds3231 rtc.

Comment: Well, if you are using your own driver, check that `CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1307` is *not* configured, because the "rtc-ds1307" driver's probe function might be called before your driver's probe function and it matches the same I2C device name string "ds3231" as your driver.

Comment: I have checked my kernel/arch/arm/config/bb.org_defconfig file. So it consists of           CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1307=y ,CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1374=y, CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1374_WDT=y, CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1672=y . In my case after inserting my module using insmod I have gone through the dmesg log there i found "rtc-ds1307 2-0068 : registered as rtc1"

Comment: After changing the configuration of CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1307 . Probe function called for my ds3231 RTC device. But I am unable to instantiate the device manually by using :echo ds3231 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-2/new_device  and unable to check the time, date using hwclock

Comment: When is your probe function called? Is it during your manual instantiation or before your manual instantiation (e.g. due to a matching node in the device tree)?

Comment: After changing the configuration of CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1307 . I am unable to do manual instantiation using echo command but if I do insert my module then I can see probe function is getting called for my specific driver(ds3231). I am using id_table matching process. Can u give me a advise that how to do it with device tree. My concern is that i need to check accurate time , insert my module and check probe function

Comment: For device tree support, your need to add a node for the I2C client device in the device tree and make its "compatible" string match an "of_match_table" in your driver. But wouldn't it be easier for you to just use the existing, working driver?

Comment: I have done it with the device tree overlay and added a RTC node in am33xx.dtsi file. I have done dynamic loading of .dtbo file in  /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/ directory . After making changes of "CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1307 is not set" I am able to insert my module using insmod and see probe is getting called. But I cannot fetch the accurate time using hwclock. Can u suggest me a way where I can insert my module and check the accurate time of external RTC.

Comment: Has the correct time been written to the RTC? Is it battery-backed to keep time when the main board is powered off? I suggest looking at the code in the existing rtc-ds1307 driver. (But I don't understand why you can't just use the existing driver instead of re-inventing the wheel.)

Comment: Basically I wrote a USB device driver code where I need to disable usb-storage so that i can add my own driver. In this format of device driver code I tried with the ds3231 RTC. Is there any module like "usb-storage" which is already holding RTC driver. Because my module is getting inserted and I found it in lsmod also.

Answer (score 0):

I too have faced this problem with reset of RTC time. This is a hardware problem. While switching from +Vcc to VBat the voltage drops even below the minimum required voltage to maintain data in EEPROM. This is visible using an oscilloscope.
Remedy is to use a Capacitor of high values between Vcc and Gnd pin. This will give the module some time to discharge from Vcc to VBat. This worked in our case.